How to extract key from a Grover's attack?
I have implemented a lightweight cipher on a quantum circuit, Now, by implementing oracle and amplifying I can increase the probability of the marked ciphered state. While there is no mechanism to extract a key from this?
I have taken additional qubits as key where all qubits are in superposition. Now, I use CNOT gates to XOR the key with the cipher text. Now, this created two problems,

My marked state fidelity decreases. In some cases, the output is not desirable.
How to extract a key, which exactly matches the ciphered text.


To be sure, you have an oracle that implements the encryption using the secret key, and you want to find the key, right? And your cipher is a one-time pad, just XORing the key with the plaintext?

I have implemented Simplified AES in qiskit, Here, 16 qubits hold the plain text and 16 qubits hold the key which is in superposition. The further processes are by CNOT gates. Now, the cipher text at output is on the first 16 qubits. Which I apply oracle on and amplify. Here, many errors arise. I want to learn to apply proper Grover's attack on this

Can you post your code here, so that we can inspect what's wrong?
